# Reduction of elliptic curves defines over general field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

let $(K,v)$ be a field with a non-archimedean valuation and let $E/K$ an elliptic curve. 
The field $K$ is not supposed to be local. We denote by $\mathcal{O}_v$ the valuation ring (not a DVR) and $M_v$ the maximal ideal.

1) I'm looking for a definition of the reduction of the elliptic curve $E$ at $v$, it is just the reduction of the coefficients of the Weierstrass equation by the map $\mathcal{O}_v \mapsto \mathcal{O}_v / M_v$ ?

2) In my case, the field $K$ is not local, so $\mathcal{O}_v$ is not a discrete valuation ring but can I have a Néron model $\mathcal{E}$ of $E$ defined over $\mathcal{O}_v$ ?

Thanks for answers !

Comment: Not sure it's defined in the literature but if such a thing exists it ought to be defined in terms of the universal property and not the Weierstrass model. What is the field $K$ you have in mind?

Comment: (see Definition 5.1 here -- the whole note is good. It's for the case that $K$ is the field of fractions of a DVR tho. http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/minimalmodel.pdf)

Comment: oh, and the "right" defn of reduction is: you have some scheme which is proper over $\text{Spec} \mathcal{O}$, so by the valuative criterion of properness any $K$-point of it extends to a $\mathcal{O}$-point, which you intersect with the special fiber. This coincides with the more concrete, usual thing for projective space and for the minimal discriminant Weierstrass model trick (as in Silverman) for elliptic curves.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and yes the definition 5.1 is only in the case were $R$ is a DVR, when the valuation is discrete. What I have in mind is just to work in the more general case : a field $K$ with a nonarchimedean valuation. Thanks for the definition of the good reduction !

Comment: Do you have a book/article for the reduction definition ?